# Why is NPM not start and deploying properly to host 3000?

Tags: javascript, node.js, powershell, react-scripts

I have latest version of node and vs code installed. I can easily install node modules but it wont start and deploy to host 3000.

Here is the error.

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\watchpack-chokidar2\node_modules\fsevents):
Starting the development server...

events.js:377
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn powershell ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:274:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:280:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21) {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn powershell',
  path: 'powershell',
  spawnargs: [
    '-NoProfile',
    '-NonInteractive',
    '–ExecutionPolicy',
    'Bypass',
    '-EncodedCommand',
    'UwB0AGEAcgB0ACAAIgBgACIAaAB0AHQAcAA6AC8ALwBsAG8AYwBhAGwAaABvAHMAdAA6ADMAMAAwADAAYAAiACIA'
  ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! reminder@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the reminder@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.     

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Im uncertain if my package.json is to blaim for the dom not deplying so here is that code below as well. let me know if you need anything additional as well. Again I dont know why it isnt automatically opening up to host 3000 and rendering things to the dom?

```
{
  "name": "reminder",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-icons": "^3.11.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "CI= react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: What command are you running (and how) that causes this error?

Comment: Hello! Thank you for replying. Im running npm start

Comment: But where? In powershell? In bash? In a vscode terminal (which)? What OS are you on?

Comment: great point, Im in vscode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved here, watch the video below and he solved it for me. not affiliated
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1sFH30JjB6E